# Replacing a character in a single field when using more than one multi-character delimiter

Tags: awk, sed

**Goal:** I would like to replace every instance of "`-`" with "`.`" between the string "`antisense`" and "`::`" in my file.

**Representative sample of my file:**

```
>-::NC_009089.1:17609-17804(+)
ATTAAATAGAAAAAATGAATTTAATATAAAAAATTAAAGAAAATTCTAAAAAAAAAAAGATAAGGTCTTA
>antisense_tadA::NC_009089.1:19643-19848(-)
TTTATAAAAATATTTAGTGTTTTTTTTAAATTAGTTCTAAAATAATTTTTAGATATTCATACAAGAGTGT
>-::NC_009089.1:20139-20394(-)
GCTGTTTTTCTATATATGAATTTTGCTACTTTTACATTATTATTATTAAAATAATCTAATTTAAACTCAT
>antisense_recR::NC_009089.1:22931-23105(+)
TCATCTATAATCGCTTTAGATAAAGCTTCCACATCATTAGTATTCATATTAATAATATGAAAAGCCAATC
>antisense_16s_rRNA::NC_009089.1:25279-26010(-)
CTCTATTTTCCTTTTTATTCTATATTTAAATTTTTTATTTACAAGAATATTTTTAATATAACATATTATG
>antisense_tRNA-Leu_tRNA-Met::NC_009089.1:30389-30422(+)
TTTACATAGAGTTAACACTCTAAAAACTGCACA
>antisense_tRNA-Arg_tRNA-Gly_tRNA-Asp_tRNA-Val::NC_009089.1:30559-31181(-)
CTTAACTTCTGTGTTCGGAATGGGAACAGGTGTATCCTCTTTCCCACCAAGTACCATCAGCGCTAAAGAG
```

**Desired output:**

```
>-::NC_009089.1:17609-17804(+)
ATTAAATAGAAAAAATGAATTTAATATAAAAAATTAAAGAAAATTCTAAAAAAAAAAAGATAAGGTCTTA
>antisense_tadA::NC_009089.1:19643-19848(-)
TTTATAAAAATATTTAGTGTTTTTTTTAAATTAGTTCTAAAATAATTTTTAGATATTCATACAAGAGTGT
>-::NC_009089.1:20139-20394(-)
GCTGTTTTTCTATATATGAATTTTGCTACTTTTACATTATTATTATTAAAATAATCTAATTTAAACTCAT
>antisense_recR::NC_009089.1:22931-23105(+)
TCATCTATAATCGCTTTAGATAAAGCTTCCACATCATTAGTATTCATATTAATAATATGAAAAGCCAATC
>antisense_16s_rRNA::NC_009089.1:25279-26010(-)
CTCTATTTTCCTTTTTATTCTATATTTAAATTTTTTATTTACAAGAATATTTTTAATATAACATATTATG
>antisense_tRNA.Leu_tRNA.Met::NC_009089.1:30389-30422(+)
TTTACATAGAGTTAACACTCTAAAAACTGCACA
>antisense_tRNA.Arg_tRNA.Gly_tRNA.Asp_tRNA.Val::NC_009089.1:30559-31181(-)
CTTAACTTCTGTGTTCGGAATGGGAACAGGTGTATCCTCTTTCCCACCAAGTACCATCAGCGCTAAAGAG
```

You'll notice above that all lines should be printed to output, but only the last two lines in this example beginning with "`>`" appear different (where each "`-`" is replaced with "`.`" between the string "`antisense`" and "`::`"). This is because the first five lines beginning with "`>`" do not have strings containing "`-`" in the described field.

I have been trying to accomplish this with *awk*, but I am open to sed solutions as well if they are easier. My general approach was to use the string "`antisense`" or "`antisense_`" as one delimiter and either "`:`" or "`::`" as the other delimiter, thus making column 2 (`$2`) the field targeted for character replacement.

Here are some of **my attempts and their erroneous outputs**:

```
$ awk -F'>antisense_|:' '/^ *>antisense_/ {gsub("-", ".", $2); print}' file
    >antisense_tadA::NC_009089.1:19643-19848(-)
    >antisense_recR::NC_009089.1:22931-23105(+)
    >antisense_16s_rRNA::NC_009089.1:25279-26010(-)
     tRNA.Leu_tRNA.Met  NC_009089.1 30389-30422(+)
     tRNA.Arg_tRNA.Gly_tRNA.Asp_tRNA.Val  NC_009089.1 30559-31181(-)

$ awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="/antisense/|:"} {gsub("-", ".", $2)} 1' file
    >-::NC_009089.1:17609-17804(+)
    ATTAAATAGAAAAAATGAATTTAATATAAAAAATTAAAGAAAATTCTAAAAAAAAAAAGATAAGGTCTTA
    >antisense_tadA::NC_009089.1:19643-19848(-)
    TTTATAAAAATATTTAGTGTTTTTTTTAAATTAGTTCTAAAATAATTTTTAGATATTCATACAAGAGTGT
    >-::NC_009089.1:20139-20394(-)
    GCTGTTTTTCTATATATGAATTTTGCTACTTTTACATTATTATTATTAAAATAATCTAATTTAAACTCAT
    >antisense_recR::NC_009089.1:22931-23105(+)
    TCATCTATAATCGCTTTAGATAAAGCTTCCACATCATTAGTATTCATATTAATAATATGAAAAGCCAATC
    >antisense_16s_rRNA::NC_009089.1:25279-26010(-)
    CTCTATTTTCCTTTTTATTCTATATTTAAATTTTTTATTTACAAGAATATTTTTAATATAACATATTATG
    >antisense_tRNA-Leu_tRNA-Met::NC_009089.1:30389-30422(+)
    TTTACATAGAGTTAACACTCTAAAAACTGCACA
    >antisense_tRNA-Arg_tRNA-Gly_tRNA-Asp_tRNA-Val::NC_009089.1:30559-31181(-)
    CTTAACTTCTGTGTTCGGAATGGGAACAGGTGTATCCTCTTTCCCACCAAGTACCATCAGCGCTAAAGAG

$ awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS="antisense|:"} {gsub("-", ".", $2)} 1' file
    >-::NC_009089.1:17609-17804(+)
    ATTAAATAGAAAAAATGAATTTAATATAAAAAATTAAAGAAAATTCTAAAAAAAAAAAGATAAGGTCTTA
    >antisense_tadA::NC_009089.1:19643-19848(-)
    TTTATAAAAATATTTAGTGTTTTTTTTAAATTAGTTCTAAAATAATTTTTAGATATTCATACAAGAGTGT
    >-::NC_009089.1:20139-20394(-)
    GCTGTTTTTCTATATATGAATTTTGCTACTTTTACATTATTATTATTAAAATAATCTAATTTAAACTCAT
    >antisense_recR::NC_009089.1:22931-23105(+)
    TCATCTATAATCGCTTTAGATAAAGCTTCCACATCATTAGTATTCATATTAATAATATGAAAAGCCAATC
    >antisense_16s_rRNA::NC_009089.1:25279-26010(-)
    CTCTATTTTCCTTTTTATTCTATATTTAAATTTTTTATTTACAAGAATATTTTTAATATAACATATTATG
    >antisense|:_tRNA.Leu_tRNA.Metantisense|:antisense|:NC_009089.1antisense|:30389-30422(+)
    TTTACATAGAGTTAACACTCTAAAAACTGCACA
    >antisense|:_tRNA.Arg_tRNA.Gly_tRNA.Asp_tRNA.Valantisense|:antisense|:NC_009089.1antisense|:30559-31181(-)
    CTTAACTTCTGTGTTCGGAATGGGAACAGGTGTATCCTCTTTCCCACCAAGTACCATCAGCGCTAAAGAG
```

I understand why/how each of my attempts fail, but I'm not sure how to properly specify more than one multi-character delimiter with awk while ensuring the defined delimiters remain unchanged between the input and output files (no replacement). **Any ideas or suggestions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example data shown this awk should work for you:

```sh
awk 'match($0, /antisense.*::/) {s = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH); 
gsub(/-/, ".", s); $0 = substr($0, 1, RSTART-1) s substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH)} 1' file

>-::NC_009089.1:17609-17804(+)
ATTAAATAGAAAAAATGAATTTAATATAAAAAATTAAAGAAAATTCTAAAAAAAAAAAGATAAGGTCTTA
>antisense_tadA::NC_009089.1:19643-19848(-)
TTTATAAAAATATTTAGTGTTTTTTTTAAATTAGTTCTAAAATAATTTTTAGATATTCATACAAGAGTGT
>-::NC_009089.1:20139-20394(-)
GCTGTTTTTCTATATATGAATTTTGCTACTTTTACATTATTATTATTAAAATAATCTAATTTAAACTCAT
>antisense_recR::NC_009089.1:22931-23105(+)
TCATCTATAATCGCTTTAGATAAAGCTTCCACATCATTAGTATTCATATTAATAATATGAAAAGCCAATC
>antisense_16s_rRNA::NC_009089.1:25279-26010(-)
CTCTATTTTCCTTTTTATTCTATATTTAAATTTTTTATTTACAAGAATATTTTTAATATAACATATTATG
>antisense_tRNA.Leu_tRNA.Met::NC_009089.1:30389-30422(+)
TTTACATAGAGTTAACACTCTAAAAACTGCACA
>antisense_tRNA.Arg_tRNA.Gly_tRNA.Asp_tRNA.Val::NC_009089.1:30559-31181(-)
CTTAACTTCTGTGTTCGGAATGGGAACAGGTGTATCCTCTTTCCCACCAAGTACCATCAGCGCTAAAGAG
```

Comment: It's almost perfect. I notice that immediately following the "`::`", the `N` from `NC` gets cut off. Would this have to do with the `/antisense.*::/` part?

Comment: Ah, yes, I just tested using `/antisense.*:/` instead and it works beautifully. Thank you anubhava!

Comment: Ah I realize my mistake in `substr`, please check updated answer now

Comment: That's actually another great fix!

Comment: I take my hat off. That was a good way to find fields in the input. I just punted to `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

While `awk` is good for a great many things, your current problem is better handled through `sed`, you can simply use the normal substitution form `sed '/match/s/find/replace/` where you have:

```
sed ':a /antisense/s/\(^[^:]*\)-\([^:]*\):/\1.\2:/;ta'
```

Where `:a` is a label that the `t` option uses to branch to on successful replacement ensuring that all `'-'` characters in lines beginning with `"antisense"` up to the first `':'` are replaced by `'.'`.

Add the `-i` option to edit a file in place with `sed -i ... file` or use `sed -i.bak ... file` to create a copy of the original in `file.bak` before replacement.

**Example**

```
$ echo "antisense_tRNA-Arg_tRNA-Gly_tRNA-Asp_tRNA-Val::NC_009089.1:30559-31181(-)" | 
  sed ':a /antisense/s/\(^[^:]*\)-\([^:]*\):/\1.\2:/;ta'
antisense_tRNA.Arg_tRNA.Gly_tRNA.Asp_tRNA.Val::NC_009089.1:30559-31181(-)
```

Comment: Very neat example of using `sed`. Thanks for sharing David! Is it faster than awk? Or what makes it better?

Comment: Both will work fine. `awk` operates on fields, while `sed` operates on a stream (`"sed"` - `"stream editor"`). You either have to shoehorn fields out of your data, or you just operate on the steam of data. Either are fine. It would be interesting to compare performance on a 1,000,000 line file (probably wouldn't be much)

Comment: _Just a quick FYI:_ The `sed` command in the bottom code sample works because it specifies to replace "`-`", but the top code sample needs the "`_`" changed to "`-`" for it to work. Simple fix!

Comment: Let me fix that, My eyes read `'-"` as `'_'` originally (getting old isn't for sissies... `:)`

Comment: N.B. `:` is not the same as `::`

Comment: I don't understand. You don't care about the second `':'`, you just want to make sure you stop replacements when you get to the first...